# PHP Ajax - combobox estado - cidades

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Quero fazer um select onde, em uma combobox, seleciono o estado e com isso abra uma nova combobox com as respectivas cidades deste estado.

Tenho isso dividido em dois arquivos:

estados.php

```
//conexao com o banco...
$rs = mysql_query("select distinct loc_uf from local ORDER BY loc_uf ASC");
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#estado').change(function(){
            $('#cidade').load('listaCidades.php?estado='+$('#estado').val());
        });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
   <body>
    <label>Estado:</label>
    <select name="estado" id="estado">
    <?php while($reg = mysql_fetch_object($rs)): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $reg->id_local ?>"><?php echo $reg->loc_uf?></option>
    <?php endwhile; 
    ?>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
    <div id="cidade"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Com isso todos os estados estao sendo listados dentro da combobox.
Agora o arquivo listaCidades.php

```
<?php
//conexao...
$estado = $_GET['estado'];

$rs = mysql_query("select loc_cidade from local where loc_uf ='".$estado."' ORDER BY loc_cidade");

echo "<label>Cidade: </label><select name='cidade'>";
while($reg = mysql_fetch_object($rs)){
    echo "<option value='$reg->loc_cidade'>$reg->loc_cidade</option>";
}
echo "</select>"; 
?>
```

Porém a combobox não está sendo preenchida corretamente.

O que estou fazendo de errado? Como capturo o valor selecionado na combo e passo como parâmetro?

tabela do banco:
     local 
campos: id_local, loc_cidade, loc_uf

Ou seja, não tenho id da UF, somente de cada cidade que respectivamente possui uma UF.

Comment: cara vc nao esta usando a variavel `$estado` na sua query, mas não entendi muito bem a disposição das sua tabelas.
Existe uma tabela para estado e outra para cidade??

Comment: a tabela é uma só. tabela LOCAL. ali tem id_local, loc_cidade e loc_uf. ou seja, o ID 1 tem uma cidade e seu estado.

Comment: cara acho q essa nao é a melhor forma de fazer essas pesquisas. Eu usei  um banco com varias tabelas - estado, cidade, bairro e dependendo da situação país.
Do jeito q está fazendo essa tabela vai ficar monstruosa, gigante mesmo.
`Se quiser pode usar a api dos correios, vc passa o cep e eles te retornam o endereco completo`

Comment: Pois é... logo notei isso também. Porém a tabela já está pronta dessa forma e preenchida. Tem como fazer dessa maneira usando essa tabela?

Comment: adicionando o estado na query funcionou?

Comment: Abaixo da linha `$estado = $_GET['estado'];` digita `echo "select loc_cidade from local where loc_uf ='".$estado."' ORDER BY loc_cidade"; die();` , depois copia o texto e joga direto no phpmyadmin, e verifica se retorna o esperando.

Comment: Não está pegando o estado selecionado: Retorna isso: select loc_cidade from local where loc_uf ='' ORDER BY loc_cidade

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99107/listar-estados-cidades-e-bairros-em-formul%C3%A1rio-de-cadastro/99133#99133

Answer (score 1):

No arquivo estados.php, o value de cada option é o campo id_local do bd, ou seja, para descobrir qual foi o estado selecionado e retornar as cidades terá que colocar:

```
WHERE id_local = $estado
```

e não loc_uf, como está no arquivo listaCidades.php.

Um pequeno adendo, as funções mysql_* estão obsoletas e devem ser removidas do php em breve, é recomendado o uso de mysqli_* ou PDO.

Comment: O que acontece é que o option selecionado no combobox não está sendo passado para a variável $estado em listaCidades.php .